# Записать список файлов в файл

Tags: файловая-система, ubuntu

Есть папка /home/kraxv. В ней куча других папок, в этих папках до 20 файлов.
Как записать в файл /home/kraxv/all.txt адрес ко всем этим файлам?
Пример:

```
/home/kraxv/a1/rxs.sh  
/home/kraxv/a1/rxs2.sh  
/home/kraxv/a1/rxs3.sh  
/home/kraxv/a2/xcvxd.sh
```

p.s. рекурсивный обход не требуется(т.е. папок в a1(и в любой другой) нет, только файлы).
pp.s. речь идёт о команде в терминал.

Comment: find /home/kraxv/ -type f > /home/kraxv/all.txt

может быть немного нужно будет параметров добавить, что бы получить желаемый вид списка.

но вообще то это вопрос на руткод.

Comment: @KoVadim

     find `pwd` -type f

Comment: может лучше даже

    find $HOME -type f

Но это детали.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
$cd /home/kraxv
$ls -R > all.txt
```

Comment: а вложенные каталоги? а полные пути?

Comment: Цитирую

"p.s. рекурсивный обход не требуется(т.е. папок в a1(и в любой другой) нет, только файлы).
 pp.s. речь идёт о команде в терминал."

Comment: прочитайте ещё раз внимательно вопрос.

Comment: Прочитал, исправил ответ. Прошу прощения.

Comment: Посмотрите на вывод. Он выдает немного другое.